# Looped sound file playback with Pyglet - Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, audio-player, pyglet

I am currently exercising how to use Python's library Pyglet. 
I want a single sound to be played in loop, but even thought I added `player.loop = True` in my  small code, the audio will only play once.
The sound file is in .wav format and is made for gapless playback.

[Here you can download the 10 seconds audio loop that I am using](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFDIi0cyGJzjHit4774plUuiAXGDnOUM/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.media import SourceGroup
player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.loop = True
source1 = pyglet.resource.media('music/wishloop.wav')
source_group = SourceGroup()
source_group.add(source1)
player.queue(source_group)
player.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried rewriting my code from scratch, and this seems to be working.
Since I only need a single file to be played on loop, this code is good enough for my needs.
If anyone would like to give me some feedback over it, please do so!

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.media import Player, load
player = Player()
player.loop = True
source = load('music/wishloop.wav')
player.queue(source)
player.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```